# Cannot fetch data from api to Gridview in fragment

Tags: java, android, gridview

if i using `extends Activity` it works normally. But when i move the code to fragment `extends Fragment` the progress bar is never stop and the data is never show up and there is no error to.

**Frag_Country_List.java**

```
public class Frag_Country_List extends Fragment implements DB_FetchDataListener {
    private String CountryFlag;
    private String CountryName;

    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private GridView myGridview;

    public Frag_Country_List() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_country_list, container, false);
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // do your variables initialisations here except Views!!!

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        return true;
    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){ super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        myGridview = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.countryGridView);
        initView();

        /*myGridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                OpenDialog();
            }
        });*/

    }

    private void initView() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this.getContext(), "", "Loading...");
        String url = "http://example.com/get_country.php";
        DB_FetchDataTask task = new DB_FetchDataTask(this);
        task.execute(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFetchComplete(List<DB_Application> data) {
        if(dialog != null)  dialog.dismiss();
        DB_ApplicationAdapter adapter = new DB_ApplicationAdapter(this.getContext(), data);
        myGridview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFetchFailure(String msg) {
        if(dialog != null)  dialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**DB_FetchDataTask.java**

```
public class DB_FetchDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    private final DB_FetchDataListener listener;
    private String msg;

    public DB_FetchDataTask(DB_FetchDataListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        if(params == null) return null;

        // get url from params
        String url = params[0];

        try {
            // create http connection
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

            // connect
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget);

            // get response
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if(entity == null) {
                msg = "No response from server";
                return null;
            }

            // get response content and convert it to json string
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            return streamToString(is);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            msg = "No Network Connection";
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String sJson) {
        if(sJson == null) {
            if(listener != null) listener.onFetchFailure(msg);
            return;
        }

        try {
            // convert json string to json array
            JSONArray aJson = new JSONArray(sJson);
            // create apps list
            List<DB_Application> apps = new ArrayList<DB_Application>();

            for(int i=0; i<aJson.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json = aJson.getJSONObject(i);
                DB_Application app = new DB_Application();
                app.setCountry(json.getString("_country"));
                app.setFlag(json.getString("_flag"));

                // add the app to apps list
                apps.add(app);
            }

            //notify the activity that fetch data has been complete
            if(listener != null) listener.onFetchComplete(apps);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            msg = "Invalid response";
            if(listener != null) listener.onFetchFailure(msg);
            return;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This function will convert response stream into json string
     * @param is respons string
     * @return json string
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public String streamToString(final InputStream is) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                throw e;
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

tell me if you need more information.

**Logcat**

```
11-27 13:54:06.007 1934-1994/com.mysql.sample E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaaa89aa0
11-27 13:54:06.177 1934-1934/com.mysql.sample E/SysUtils: ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
11-27 13:54:06.185 1934-1934/com.mysql.sample E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
11-27 13:54:06.185 1934-1934/com.mysql.sample E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
11-27 13:54:06.215 1934-1934/com.mysql.sample E/DataReductionProxySettingListener: No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your `onViewCreated` code to `onCreateView` method:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_country_list, container, false);
        myGridview = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.countryGridView);
        initView();
        return view;
     }
```